# how to animate the uilabel view which has some text , in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uilabel

in my app i am planing to add the animation for the textLabels, which should come from left side of the screen

i have used following code but its crashing

```
(void)animateLoop {

    UILabel *mylab;
    mylab.text=@"SAAAAdiiiii";
    mylab.frame = CGRectMake(-mylab.bounds.size.width, 100, mylab.bounds.size.width, mylab.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"timesquare" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:(YES)];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];

    mylab.frame = CGRectMake(480, 100, mylab.bounds.size.width, mylab.bounds.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
 }
```

n i called this in the viewDidload

but it was crashing at this line    mylab.text=@"SAAAAdiiiii";   crashLog:invalidargument

can any one tell me how can i  animate the uilabel

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alloced the UILabel . means first create the memory for you label ...

```
UILabel *mylab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
mylab.text=@"SAAAAdiiiii";
```

Suggest you to have  `UILabel *mylab;` as `iVar` , because it has to be `released`.

Comment: ya ya i ill change that variable name,,thanx for ur time

Comment: @Ravi : Also add it in superview using `addSubview` function as suggested by @Sascha .

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate and init your UILabel first..
instead of `UILabel *mylab;` try `UILabel *mylab = [[UILabel alloc] init];`

You also have to release it somewhere and you have to add the label to your view (something like `[self.view addSubview:mylab];`).